# Two state markov process time distribution in given state

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-process

Suppose that there is a time-continuous markov process with 2 states, $A$ and $B$. The transition rate from $A$ to $B$ is $\beta$ and from $B$ to $A$ is $\alpha$. I'm interested in finding the distribution of the fraction of time that "particles" spend in state $B$ as the system evolves over some time $t$, assuming that the system is always at steady state.

Because the system is in steady state, its obvious that the expected fraction of time spent in $B$ is always going to be $\frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta}$.

At very small times $t$ there have been no transitions, and so $\frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta}$ particles will have been in state $B$ for the entire time, while $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}$ particles will have been in state $A$ for the entire time, averaging out to our expectation value. On the other hand, at very long times $t$ every single particle will have been in state $B$ for $\frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta}$ of the time, so we again get our expectation value but with a very different distribution for the fraction of time spent in state $B$.

I'm trying to figure out how to describe the distribution for intermediate times. I've been reading a fair amount about Markov processes, but I haven't found anything that discusses this sort of idea. I would really appreciate if anyone could give any pointers on how to proceed with this or where to look/what to read.

Comment: Your description of a Markov chain in terms of plural "particles" is unusual. For a Markov chain there is only one object that is moving about the state space.  At any instant of time, that object can either be in state A or state B.  You can call the object a "particle" if you like, but there are not multiple objects/particles, there is only one.

Comment: Take the "particles" to mean different independent parallel chains then

Comment: Note that if we start in steady state (at time $t=0$) then we are always in steady state and for any $t\geq 0$ and interval size $T>0$ we have $E[\frac{1}{T}\int_t^{t+T} 1_{\{X(t)=B\}}dt] = \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}$ (where $1_{\{X(t)=B\}}$ is an indicator function that is 1 if $X(t)=B$ and 0 else).  But perhaps you are looking for transient behavior of $P[X(t)=B]$ given either $X(0)=A$ or $X(0)=B$ (which is easy to solve for this 2-state chain using an ODE approach).

Comment: Did you read my question? I stated the expectation is obvious and that I am not looking for the chance that it is found in a given state but rather the distribution of total time spent in that state.

Comment: I indeed read over the question.  I am still trying to imagine how the multiple independent particles of the story relate to the specific underlying problem that you want to solve.  It seems to me that it makes more sense to treat one particle.  It is difficult to know what you want from the paragraphs you wrote and I have introduced some equations for one particle. I suppose, as you want to talk about many particles, you will want to average over all of them and perhaps introduce $n$ (a number of particles) somewhere.  I leave all of these obvious details to you.